# How to override Magento 2 js using Mixins?

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides, knockoutjs, mixins

I want to override the js file in `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default.js` using mixins. Here is my requirejs code:

```
var config = 
{
    config: 
    {
        mixins: 
        {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default':
            {
                'Anowave_Ec/js/totals-processor/default/plugin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And here is my override file

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        estimateTotals: function (address) {
            var serviceUrl, payload;
            totalsService.isLoading(true);
            serviceUrl = resourceUrlManager.getUrlForTotalsEstimationForNewAddress(quote),
                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        address: _.pick(address, this.requiredFields)
                    }
                };

            if (quote.shippingMethod() && quote.shippingMethod()['method_code']) {
                payload.addressInformation['shipping_method_code'] = quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'];
                payload.addressInformation['shipping_carrier_code'] = quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code'];
            }

            storage.post(
                serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(payload), false
            ).done(
                function (result) {
                    quote.setTotals(result);
                    /** I added new codes on this part **/
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    errorProcessor.process(response);
                }
            ).always(
                function () {
                    totalsService.isLoading(false);
                }
            );
        }
    };

    return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/.../columns returns.
        return target.extend(mixin); // new result that all other modules receive
    };
});
```

I simply followed the documentation on Magento2 site but I'm getting errors like

> target is not a function

Comment: do you get solution ?

Answer (score 2):

These some ways to overwrite core Magento 2 JS using **mixin**

- With js file returned **$.mage.[widgetName]**

  Your target file must be using **$.widget**:

ex: source file: **Magento_Checkout/js/shopping-cart**

```
return function(originalShoppingCart){
        $.widget('mage.shoppingCart',originalShoppingCart, {
             //Overwrite function here.
        });
        return $.mage.shoppingCart;
}
```

- With js file returned an Object: return { /* Code */ };

Must Return **target** variable

```
    return function (target) {
        var registerStep = target.registerStep;
        target.registerStep = function (code, alias, title, isVisible, navigate, sortOrder) {
            //Before Function.. 
            registerStep.apply(this,[code, alias, title, isVisible, navigate, sortOrder]); //Remove this line to skip call default function. 
            //After Function 
        };
        return target;
    };
```

**Update**: More detail: [Rewrite JS in Magento 2](https://solutiontutorials.com/development/magento-2/how-to-override-magento-2-js-using-mixins/)

Comment: The first one (With js file returned $.mage.[widgetName]) worked for me. Thanks a lot. But be careful because if you use this, you will need to check if some file used this name or not. Ex: $.mage.shoppingCart is used, then you won't see any error in log file or chrome console but your function still not working.

Comment: In case of comment recommended read this: https://solutiontutorials.com/development/magento-2/how-to-override-magento-2-js-using-mixins/

Answer (score 0):

Kindly do like below code

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'mage/storage',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
], function (_, resourceUrlManager, quote, storage, totalsService, errorProcessor, cartCache, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin =
    {   

        estimateTotals: function (address) {
            var data = {
                shippingMethodCode: null,
                shippingCarrierCode: null
            };

            if (quote.shippingMethod() && quote.shippingMethod()['method_code']) {
                data.shippingMethodCode = quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'];
                data.shippingCarrierCode = quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code'];
            }

            if (!cartCache.isChanged('cartVersion', customerData.get('cart')()['data_id']) &&
                !cartCache.isChanged('shippingMethodCode', data.shippingMethodCode) &&
                !cartCache.isChanged('shippingCarrierCode', data.shippingCarrierCode) &&
                !cartCache.isChanged('address', address) &&
                cartCache.get('totals')
            ) {
                quote.setTotals(cartCache.get('totals'));
            } else {
                loadFromServer(address);
            }
        }

    };

    return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/.../default returns.
        return target.extend(mixin); // new result that all other modules receive 
    };

});
```

I have not tested but might be it will work.